# How do I disable interactive session (kubectl exec) to a Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to disable interactive session/ssh access to a Kubernetes pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s controlled via the RBAC system, via the pods/exec subresource. You can set up your policies however you want.

Comment: As addition to coderanger answer, docs regarding RBAC: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/